# Compare columns and output a value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Based on fields containing the Release Name and Change Date, I need to determine in what stage of that release process, the change occurred.

In the example below, the change occurred in the January Analysis stage. I need to do this a few hundred times.

You are given a Month and Date.

You will see the month, phase, and date range (Start & Calculation End). The month and date range are used to determine the phase. Therefore for January 10/10/17 falls between January 10/9/17 -  11/5/2017 which would put it in the Analysis phase.

Below is a link to an image of how the Stage is determined and spreadsheet is setup.

Phase Determination
[image: Phase Determination]

```
Release   Change Date
January   10/10/2017

Release   Stage                Start        Calculation End
January   Form Release         8/14/2017    9/10/2017
January   Requirements Review  9/11/2017    10/8/2017
January   Analysis             10/9/2017    11/5/2017
January   Development          11/6/2017    12/10/2017
January   Functional Test      12/11/2017   12/17/2017
January   QA                   12/18/2017   1/7/2018
January   Live                 1/7/2018     1/7/2018
February  Form Release         9/11/2017    10/8/2017
February  Requirements Review  10/9/2017    11/5/2017
February  Analysis             11/6/2017    12/10/2017
February  Development          12/11/2017   1/7/2018
February  Functional Test      1/8/2018     1/14/2018
February  QA                   1/15/2018    2/11/2018
February  Live                 2/11/2018    2/11/2018
```

Reference Error 
[image: Reference Errore]

Evaluate Formula
[image: Evaluate Formula]

Comment: I don't think is very clear your question. What did you used to determine that the change occured in January Analysis?

Comment: If you look below the line Release Stage Start Calculation End you will see the month, phase, and date range. The month and date range are used to determine the phase. Therefore for January 10/10/17 fals between January 10/9/17 -  11/5/2017 which would put it in the Analysis phase. I hope this clarifies the issue

Comment: Are the Month and the Date in one cell, side by side, or what?

Comment: side by side so in different cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a relatively straightforward way to do this, as I understand the question.

1. Create a named range for each month - e.g. in the screenshot, "January" would correspond to `A2:D8`, and "February" to `A9:D15`.
2. Then use `INDIRECT` to refer to that named range, and `INDEX` and `MATCH` to return the stage. Within your `MATCH` function, you will use an `INDEX` and `INDIRECT` to get the 3rd (Start) column of the range "January", in which you will try to match your date. The *match_type* argument (3rd argument of `MATCH`) is 1, meaning that it finds the largest value that is *less than* the lookup value. This will give you your row number. Then in your outermost INDEX formula, the column number is 2 (the Stage column).

This is the formula in `H2`:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(F2),MATCH(G2,INDEX(INDIRECT(F2),,3),1),2)
```

[image]

Comment: I get a reference error when trying this any suggestions?

Comment: Use Formulas > Evaluate Formula - what part of the formula gives you the REF error?

Comment: I have attached the reference error. [Reference Error][1]

Comment: Did you create named ranges "January", "February" and so on?

Comment: How would i go about doing that? Also I just want to say thanks for the assist!

Comment: Select A2:A8, then in the dropdown box right above A2, type "January"... repeat for February, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a VBA macro to loop through the rows in the table and look for the row that matches the criteria. Below is some VBA that will do it, you can modify this code to use cell references for the inputs, and for the range to search instead of ActiveSheet.UsedRange if you want.

```
Sub getStage()
    Dim release As String
    release = "January"
    Dim eventDate As Date
    eventDate = "2017-10-10"

    For Each Row In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
        If (Row.Cells(1, 1) = release And Row.Cells(1, 3) <= eventDate And Row.Cells(1, 4) >= eventDate) Then
            Debug.Print (Row.Cells(1, 2))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```